# why i cant to get console.log(req.body)? in express, sqlite

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express

i have a problem 
the problem is i cant to get 'console.log(req.body)'

In my test cases, email('123@gmail.com') and password('1234') goes my controller folder
i expected a 'req.body.email = '123@gmail.com' ', 'req.body.password = '1234'. 
but, In my terminal, nothing happens! 
It does not working console.log!

I have installed 'bodyParser, cors, session...' everything i can solve this..
but I unsolved it.

below is my code.

```js
((((( in my controller folder ))))
const {user} = require('./models')
module.expots = {
signInController: (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)    <<<<<<<<<<<< IT DOES NOT WORKING
}

(((in ./models/user)))
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const user = sequelize.define(
    'user',
    {
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
      password: DataTypes.STRING,
      username: DataTypes.STRING,
      mobile: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {}
  );
  user.associate = function (models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return user;
};


(((( index.js ))))
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql2');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//
const app = express();
require('./models');

const {
  signInController,
  signUpController,
  userContoroller,
} = require('./controllers');

const port = 4001;
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true },
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: This is misspelled: `module.expots = {`.

Comment: Where is `signInController()` actually used in your code.  You show its definition. You show importing it.  But, you don't show actually using it as a request handler or as middleware.